# What does each definition in configtx.yaml means in Hyperledger fabric v1.0?

Tags: networking, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, topology, consensus

This is related to Hyperledger fabric v1.0 network topology.
From the example, configtx.yaml contains following definitions:

```
Profiles:

    TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
    TwoOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
```

There are two main sections.

1. TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis
   This defines the orderer service and the genesis block details.
2. TwoOrgsChannel
   This defines the channel details. Such as how many organization/entity are going to be part of the channel.

What I understood from the documentation is Consortiums section defines what are the organizations/entities belongs to a Consortium.

My questions:

1. What is the role of Consortium?
2. Can a Consortium entity would have peer nodes running for it's own?
3. If yes, how to configure in this yaml file?
4. What is the meaning of <<: line?
5. What is Application in this context?
6. Can I define multiple profiles in this yaml file?

appreciate if anyone can explain in details.

Comment: 4. <<: is just a method to inherit properties in YAML: https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I thought it was fabric related notation. The link you attached helped me a lot to understand yaml.

Answer (score 1):

My questions:

What is the role of Consortium?

> A consortium consists of organizations. And organization contains
>   peers or orderer. one channel is matched with one consortium but one
>   consortium can be matched many consortiums.

Can a Consortium entity would have peer nodes running for it's own?
If yes, how to configure in this yaml file?

> No, but if you want to define consortium, you have to get MSPs about
>   organizations.

What is the meaning of <<: line?

> It's a YAML grammar.

What is Application in this context?

> channel application like Node.js Application. But now My channel works without the section.

Can I define multiple profiles in this yaml file?

> sorry, I don't understand what you want to define profile for.

Answer (score 1):

to reply to "Can I define multiple profiles in this yaml file?" the answer is yes. 
As you can see in this sample [file](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-test/blob/master/feature/configs/configtx.yaml#L334), multiple profiles are here defined.

Profiles are used to defines the configuration of the genesis block and to define the first channel configuration transaction. In the code that you provide `TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis` should be used as parameter for the configtxgen command

```
configtxgen -profile SampleSingleMSPSolo -channelID sys-channel -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
```

while the second is used to generate the artifacts for the channel transaction

```
configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID channel-name
```

In the above file you can check some different configurations... I think it is a good starting point to understand the network configuration which is still something I'm trying to fully figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question "What is the meaning of <<: line?"

yaml files syntax :-

The & marks an alias for the node (in your example &default aliases the development node as "default") and the * references the aliased node with the name "default". The <<: inserts the content of that node.

This type reference are used when - Repeated nodes (objects) are first identified by an anchor (marked with the ampersand - “&”), and are then aliased (referenced with an asterisk - “*”) thereafter.